# How to add content to PHP include files?

Tags: php, html, web, include

Ok I may not have the best title , but I will try to give a better explanation.

Let's assume you are using PHP include() to structure your website:

**Header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name=keywords content="somthiefn"/>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

**Footer.php**

```
    </body>
</html>
```

Then a sample page:

**Index.php**

```
<!--Header-->
<?php include ('includes/header.php'); ?>

   <div class="content">
       <!-- some content-->
   </div>

<!--Footer-->
<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Basically I just want to know if there is a way to load some script into my header section.

I would like to achieve something like ASP.NET and its master Page, where I can just add content the header. for example

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/somescript.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Scrips should ideally be placed before `</body>` in the footer

Comment: @popnoodles yes I know, this was just an example, because I need to do the same with `css` files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **index.php**, before you include **header.php**, you could set an array for your scripts like:

**header.php**

```
<?php if(!isset($scripts)) $scripts = array(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name=keywords content="somthiefn"/>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.ico" />

        <!-- Include dynamic scripts-->
        <?php foreach($scripts in $script): ?>
        <script src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    </head>
    <body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$scripts = array('Scripts/somescript.js', 'http://server.com/path/anoterscript.js);
?>

<!--Header-->
<?php include ('includes/header.php'); ?>

   <div class="content">
       <!-- some content-->
   </div>

<!--Footer-->
<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Nop, because **foreach** would break at start, `$scripts = array()` are setted at the top of **header.php** for security, if you don't define this in your `index.php` it's no problem.

Comment: With this code example **$scripts** will always be empty :) $scripts = array();

Comment: True! I change it: `<?php if(!isset($scripts)) $scripts = array(); ?>`. I changed **foreach** too.

Comment: is this php? **foreach($script in $scripts)** or should it be **foreach($scripts as $script)**

Comment: Yes, use `foreach($scripts as $script)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do like this:

index.php

```
<?php
    // Wanted page title 
    $title = "some";

    // JS Files.. 
    $scripts = array();  
    $scripts[] = '<script src="js/some.js" />';
    $scripts[] = '<script src="js/some2.js" />';
    $scripts[] = '<script src="js/some3.js" />';

    // Include header 
    include ('includes/header.php');
```

header.php

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
<?php echo implode("\n",$scripts) ?>
```

Of course the variables could be named as you want and contain any data. Main thing is that you can pass them between files like i showed.

Comment: yes this makes sense but what if I have multiple scripts, one variable can hold that?

Comment: Changed my answer to do that.

Comment: This is very close but I get an error `implode() Invalid arguments passed in` is this the right way to push elements to the array. error only when more then one.

Comment: Yes it is. Try with just **implode(" ",$scripts);** and check your $scripts array values.

Comment: Tried it same error, this looked like the cleanest solution unfortunately I get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add PHP code to the header? Then you can add your code between  tags (or  tags if short tags are enabled), but I would consider to just call an include between the PHP tags and have the logic in that include.

Another option could be a template engine, e. g. [Smarty](http://smarty.net/). In most of the templates engine you can define your own functions and call them from the templates.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
// content.php
<?php
$head = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='keywords' content='somthiefn' />
    <title>Website</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
    <script src='Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <link type='image/png' rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' />
  </head>
<body>";
$foot = "\n<body>\n</html>";
?>

// index.php
<?php
include 'includes/content.php';
$dom = new DOMDocument; @$dom->loadHTML($head);
$hd = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head'); $hd = $hd->item(0);
$script = $dom->creatElement('script');
$scriptAttr = $dom->createAttribute('src');
$scriptAttr->value= 'Scripts/somescript.js'; $script->appendChild($scriptAttr);
$hd->appendChild($script);
echo $dom->saveHTML().$foot;
?>
```

The other option is to use variables to separate your code then only `echo` portions. That is what I would do. It's technologically faster. Try this:

```
// content.php
<?php
$headTop = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='keywords' content='somthiefn' />
    <title>Website</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
    <script src='Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>\n    ";
$headBottom = "\n    <link type='image/png' rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' />
  </head>
<body>";
$foot = "\n<body>\n</html>";
?>

// index.php
<?php
include 'includes/content.php';
echo "$headTop<script src='Scripts/somescript.js'></script>$headBottom$foot";
?>
```

You can see why you would use the second option.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It dynamically loads title, scripts and styles.

**header.php**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($scripts))
        $scripts = array();

    if(!isset($styles))
        $styles = array();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/somestyle.css" type="text/css">
        <script src=somescript.js"></script>

        <!-- include styles -->
        <?php foreach($styles as $style): ?>
            <link href="<?php echo $style; ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <!-- include scripts-->
        <?php foreach($scripts as $script): ?>
            <script src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </head>
    <body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $title = "some dynamic title";
    $scripts = array('js/somescript.js', 'http://server.com/anoterscript.js');
    $styles = array('css/somestyle.css', 'css/anotherstyle.css');

    require_once ('header.php');
?>

   <div class="content">
       <!-- some content-->
   </div>

<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```