# include('form.php') throw error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing page-contact.php for a WordPress website contact page. Where I insert form.php through the following code snippet

```
<?php
include ('form.php');
```

But running over the localhost, throw a 404 error. While accessing form.php in browser work fine as expected.

```
<form id="contact" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post">
 // some code here
</form>
```

This is the inside the form.php

Comment: You don't need the () i believe. Check out this manual for how to use the include function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Use the absolute path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add content to PHP include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589482/how-to-add-content-to-php-include-files)

Comment: Could you provide path of both scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute path (due to your example this example assumes your form.php is in the same directory. Otherwise you´d need to adjust the path):

```
include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'form.php';
```

In the form.php, you have $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . I think due to security issues it would be better to use

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" >
```

Comment: Yes my form.php is at the same directory, I also used require instead of inlcude but didn't cause fatal error, means it is successfuly included.

Comment: Changing the form attributes to the above mentioned still cause 404 error.

Comment: After making the above two changes, the inspect tool of chrome showed <form method="POST" action="/wordpress_directory/contact/" >.